# Save Config Button does not work when <frontend_model> tag is added in system.xml file

Tags: magento2, frontend-model

I am adding color picker in system configuration fields.
My block class is at `vendor/Module/Block/Color.php`

```
<?php
namespace PME\SuccessPage\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    // Attach the color picker
                    $el.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

I have added js libraries at:
`vendor/module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml`
as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

When I uncomment `<frontend_model>vendor/module/Block/Color</frontend_model>` in `system.xml` file **save config** button stops working!!
My field in `System.xml` is:

```
<group id="design_section" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="35" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Design Section</label>
                <field id="display" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Display Fields</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="link_color" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>vendor\module\Block\Color</frontend_model>
                    <depends>
                        <field id="display">1</field>
                    </depends>
                </field>
            </group>
```

[image: This Save Config button does not work when i uncomment <frontend_model> tag in system.xml file]

Comment: correction: adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>

Comment: correction: when form system.xml file I uncomment <frontend_model>vendor/module/Block/Color.php</frontend_model> in a field Save config button stops working

Comment: might be this problem is due to js libraries added at
vendor/module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

Comment: My problem is solved by removing js library from vendor/module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml